# It's throwing Exception: System.NullReferenceException .How I can solve it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
    Line 31:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetContact");
    Line 32:             cmd.CommandType =  CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Line 33:             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", ViewState["fname"].ToString());
    Line 34:             cmd.Connection = con;
    Line 35:             sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the line that is throwing the exception from the exception details - In this line, check that every variable you are using has been correctly initialized.

```
ViewState["fname"].ToString()
```

viewstate having value or it's null